# Where to add a CFLAG, such as -std=gnu99, into an autotools project

Tags: c, autotools

I have a simple Autotools C project (not C++).

CFLAGs (by inspection) seem to be `-g -O2`.

I want all of the generated make files to also have `-std=gnu99` appended to the CFLAGs, because I use `for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)` and similar.

I can obviously hack the Makefile, but this gets overwritten on `./configure`.

Where is the correct place to add (or change) CFLAGs which are required by the code (as opposed to those CFLAGs which the user might want to change)?

(Note this is partial duplicate of [Where to add a CFLAG, such as -std=gnu99, into an (Eclipse CDT) autotools project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633763/where-to-add-a-cflag-such-as-std-gnu99-into-an-eclipse-cdt-autotools-project) as I was getting Eclipse-specific answers which I didn't want.)

---

@DevSolar's answer has not helped yet.  A `configure.ac` file (below) generates the `configure` script (also below).

configure.ac:

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -std=gnu99"
AC_PREREQ(2.59)
AC_INIT(tuntest, 1.0)


AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()

AC_PROG_CC

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile src/Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

$ grep CFLAGS configure

```
CFLAGS
CFLAGS
To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
ac_compile='$CC -c $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext >&5'
ac_link='$CC -o conftest$ac_exeext $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS >&5'
ac_compile='$CC -c $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext >&5'
ac_link='$CC -o conftest$ac_exeext $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS >&5'
ac_test_CFLAGS=${CFLAGS+set}
ac_save_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
   CFLAGS="-g"
  CFLAGS=""
     CFLAGS="-g"
if test "$ac_test_CFLAGS" = set; then
  CFLAGS=$ac_save_CFLAGS
    CFLAGS="-g -O2"
    CFLAGS="-g"
    CFLAGS="-O2"
    CFLAGS=
ac_compile='$CC -c $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext >&5'
ac_link='$CC -o conftest$ac_exeext $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS >&5'
```

Comment: Maybe you want to set `CFLAGS` when do configure, for example: `./configure CFLAGS="-g -O2 -std=gnu99"`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing.  The CFLAG I wish to add `-std=gnu99` is essential, therefore I want it not be be something that the user has to configure.  The code will not compile without it, so it must always be there, hence the question.

Comment: Then how about `./configure CC="gcc -std=gnu99"`?

Comment: I want the **user** to not have to add `-std=gnu99` anywhere.  It needs to be added as a result of configuration somewhere in one of the autotools files.  My objective is for the user to do `./configure` `make` `sudo make install` as normal.

Comment: How about adding `CFLAGS` (or updating if it exists) in `configure.ac` or `configure.in`?

Comment: @another.anon.coward - This is what I'm looking for and I have tried various variants, but haven't made it work yet (I don't know autotools well and the syntax/semantics of these files are a mystery to me).  Could you answer with a working example?

Comment: Do you have `configure.in` or `configure.ac` file in the project? Is it a particular open source project or something of your own?

Comment: @another.anon.coward  It's something of my own.  Yes, there are both `configure.in` and `configure.ac` files.  I think autotools may generate one from the other, so I must be careful to use the 'upstream' file.  I don't know which this is.  Could you post an example of the syntax needed?

Comment: Note that I deleted my answer as the alternatives are much better.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

autoconf has a macro for this:

Just put:

```
AC_PROG_CC_STDC
```

after your `AC_PROG_CC` and everything will be right.

Especially when you use other compilers that do not have `-std=gnu99` but operate in C99 mode by default (or have a different option hpcc's `-AC99` springs to mind).

I would **NOT** use `CFLAGS` for that kind of thing.

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/C-Compiler.html):

```
-- Macro: AC_PROG_CC_STDC
If the C compiler cannot compile ISO Standard C (currently C99),
try to add an option to output variable `CC' to make it work.  If
the compiler does not support C99, fall back to supporting ANSI
C89 (ISO C90).

After calling this macro you can check whether the C compiler has
been set to accept Standard C; if not, the shell variable
`ac_cv_prog_cc_stdc' is set to `no'.
```

Comment: How does this cooperate with GCC's `-std=c99` vs. `-std=gnu99`?

Comment: it will automatically use `-std=gnu99` if the compiler is gcc or supports it.

Comment: Any chance of asking for *non-extended* behaviour (`-std=c99`) explicitly? (Not what OP asked for, just out of interest - I don't care for GNU extensions, personally.)

Comment: if you want gcc's `-std=c99` explicitly, just use `./configure CC="gcc -std=c99"` or put it in a profile.  The macro will detect that and report compliancy.

Comment: @DevSolar: Looking at the macro definition it is just a tiny hack to support a different default list

Comment: If you want the latest standard, then `AC_PROG_CC_STDC` is the way to go. If you want C99 explicitly, then you want the `AC_PROG_CC_C99` macro instead. See here: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/C-Compiler.html#C-Compiler

Answer (score 4):

Although using a macro like `AC_PROG_CC_STDC` is preferable to adding  compiler options to CFLAGS, autoconf currently has no macros enabling C11 compiler support -- there is no `AC_PROG_CC_C11` yet, and `AC_PROG_CC_STDC` only adds the `-std=gnu99` option for gcc instead of `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11`.

You can add compiler flags simply by putting

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -std=c11"
```

in the configure.ac.

Alternatively, it might be better to check first if the compiler supports the added option, and print a warning otherwise, telling the user to manually add an equivalent option to CFLAGS that works for their compiler:

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c11],
  [AX_APPEND_FLAG([-std=c11])],
  [AC_MSG_WARN([-std=c11 not supported, you may have to set CFLAGS to enable C11 support.])
])
```

This uses the `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` and `AX_APPEND_FLAG` macros found in the [GNU Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/). To use them, put them into an `m4` subdirectory and add `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` to configure.ac

Comment: A slightly simpler way, although without the option to customize the warning message, is to use: AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS([-std=c11 -foo -bar])

Comment: `CFLAGS+=" -std=c11"` - You should not be changing `CFLAGS`. The user owns them, not Autoconf or Automake. The answer lies in `AM_CFLAGS` and its per-target variants, but no one has provided an answer for it. @Arjun came close, but the answer was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is covered in the Automake manual, [27.6 Flag Variables Ordering](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html). There an interaction between `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`, and its more than just setting a well known shell variable used in implicit make rules.

The short of it is, you should set it in a new variable called something like `mumble_CFLAGS` discussed in the Automake manual. `mumble` is just the name of your program, and it is often `foo` or `bar` in other examples. Later, when your makefile is created, the recipe for your program (`mumble` or `foo` or `bar`) will use `$(mumble_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)` to build the target.

Here is an example of how it might look. Instead of using `mumble` or `foo` or `bar`, it uses `my_prog` as a artifact name.

***configure.ac***:

```
# Perform a compile test using -std=gnu99, set has_gnu99
if test "$has_gnu99" -eq "1"; then
  AC_SUBST([MY_GNU99], [-std=gnu99])
fi
```

***Makefile.am***:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = my_prog
my_prog_CFLAGS = $(MY_GNU99) $(MY_ANOTHER_FLAG) $(MY_YET_ANOTHER_FLAG) ...
```

Later, when the makefile is generated, it will have a recipe similar to the following, where `$(MY_PROG_CFLAGS)` is applied to all the objects that build `my_prog`:

```
my_prog :
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(MY_PROG_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The extra indirections of `my_prog_CFLAGS` allows you to have multiple flags for different targets. For example, you could have a `my_prog_CFLAGS`, a `my_archive_CFLAGS` and a `my_sharedobj_CFLAGS`.

And its not limited to `my_prog_CFLAGS`. You could also have `my_prog_CPPFLAGS`, `my_prog_CXXFLAGS` and other variables used implicitly in makefiles.

---

This is from the [Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html):

> ***Compile Flag Variables***
>
> This section attempts to answer all the above questions. We will
>   mostly discuss CPPFLAGS in our examples, but actually the answer holds
>   for all the compile flags used in Automake: CCASFLAGS, CFLAGS,
>   CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, FCFLAGS, FFLAGS, GCJFLAGS, LDFLAGS, LFLAGS,
>   LIBTOOLFLAGS, OBJCFLAGS, OBJCXXFLAGS, RFLAGS, UPCFLAGS, and YFLAGS.
>
> CPPFLAGS, AM_CPPFLAGS, and mumble_CPPFLAGS are three variables that
>   can be used to pass flags to the C preprocessor (actually these
>   variables are also used for other languages like C++ or preprocessed
>   Fortran). CPPFLAGS is the user variable (see User Variables),
>   AM_CPPFLAGS is the Automake variable, and mumble_CPPFLAGS is the
>   variable specific to the mumble target (we call this a per-target
>   variable, see Program and Library Variables).
>
> Automake always uses two of these variables when compiling C sources
>   files. When compiling an object file for the mumble target, the first
>   variable will be mumble_CPPFLAGS if it is defined, or AM_CPPFLAGS
>   otherwise. The second variable is always CPPFLAGS.
>
> In the following example,
>
> ```
> bin_PROGRAMS = foo bar
> foo_SOURCES = xyz.c
> bar_SOURCES = main.c
> foo_CPPFLAGS = -DFOO
> AM_CPPFLAGS = -DBAZ
> ```
>
> xyz.o will be compiled with ‘$(foo_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)’, (because
>   xyz.o is part of the foo target), while main.o will be compiled with
>   ‘$(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)’ (because there is no per-target variable
>   for target bar).
>
> The difference between mumble_CPPFLAGS and AM_CPPFLAGS being clear
>   enough, let’s focus on CPPFLAGS. CPPFLAGS is a user variable, i.e., a
>   variable that users are entitled to modify in order to compile the
>   package. This variable, like many others, is documented at the end of
>   the output of ‘configure --help’.
>
> For instance, someone who needs to add /home/my/usr/include to the C
>   compiler’s search path would configure a package with
>
> ```
> ./configure CPPFLAGS='-I /home/my/usr/include'
> ```
>
> and this flag would be propagated to the compile rules of all
>   Makefiles.