# Append compile flags to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS while configuration/make

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, automake

The project that I am trying to build has default flags

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2

CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
```

I need to append a flag `-w` to both these variables (to remove: 'consider all warnings as errors')

I have a method to work it out, give

```
make 'CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O2 -w'; 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -w'
```

OR

Run `./configure` and statically modify `Makefile`

But I want to append my options with the existing options while running `configure` or `make`

The post
[Where to add a CFLAG, such as -std=gnu99, into an autotools project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647208/where-to-add-a-cflag-such-as-std-gnu99-into-an-autotools-project)
conveniently uses a macro to achieve this.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You almost have it right; why did you add the semicolon?

To do it on the `configure` line:

```
 ./configure CFLAGS='-g -O2 -w' CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -w'
```

To do it on the `make` line:

```
 make CFLAGS='-g -O2 -w' CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -w'
```

However, that doesn't really remove *consider all warnings as errors*; that removes all warnings.  So specifying both `-Wall` and `-w` doesn't make sense.  If you want to keep the warnings but not have them considered errors, use the `-Wall -Wno-error` flags.

Alternatively, most `configure` scripts which enable `-Werror` by default also have a flag such as `--disable-werror` or similar.  Run `./configure --help` and see if there's something like that.

Comment: Is there a way for me to NOT specify this statitcally evertime, like,
CFLAGS=' $CFLAGS <my-options>', to retain whatever is already configured and without knowing it as well.

Comment: No, that's not possible (at least not without modifying the makefile).  According to the autoconf coding standards the default value of `CFLAGS` is always only enabling debugging/optimization, so it should normally always be `-g -O2` for most systems.  It's not correct (according to the coding standards) to add other important flags such as `-I`, `-D`, etc. into `CFLAGS`.  So it should be safe to always just override it.

Comment: If you cannot assign CFLAGS without retaining the package defaults, then the software packaging contains a bug which should be reported to the package maintainer.