# Adding -lrt to the compilation when running ./configure

Tags: unix, makefile, configure

I've been messing around with some source files (coreutils package source for example), adding to them asynchronous I/O functionality. Now I want to compile, but I need to add -lrt flag to gcc.

What I did is shoving it somewhere to the *Makefile* file. It once took me an hour to find where to put it so it will work.

I wonder, is there a way to add it during the *./configure* phase, so the *Makefile* will be created automatically and things will just compile with the *-lrt* flag?

I've tried configuring the additional flag with:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-g -O2 -lrt'
```

and indeed I see a change in the *Makefile*, but it still doesn't work.

Using

```
make V=1
```

I see that *make* executes:

```
gcc -std=gnu99   -g -O2 -lrt -Wl,--as-needed  -o src/wc src/wc.o src/libver.a lib/libcoreutils.a  lib/libcoreutils.a
```

notice that *-lrt* is somewhere in the middle, so for some reason it doesn't work. But if this get executed:

```
gcc -std=gnu99   -g -O2 -Wl,--as-needed  -o src/wc src/wc.o src/libver.a lib/libcoreutils.a  lib/libcoreutils.a -lrt
```

it works. Notice that *-lrt* is at the end.

How can I append a flag to the end automatically through *./configure*? or is there some other way to do that?

**Partial Solution:**
After running *./configure*, I've edited the *Makefile* and added *-lrt* to the *LDADD* variable - that done the trick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23407800/539465

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append compile flags to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS while configuration/make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407635/append-compile-flags-to-cflags-and-cxxflags-while-configuration-make)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but overriding CFLAGS doesn't work. I've edited my question with further details regarding the CFLAGS.

Comment: It seems like editing LDADD in Makefile does the trick. I looked for a way ./configure will do that automatically, but I can live with editing the Makefile manually if there is no other solution.