# What is the makefile option to debug mixed C and CPP programs?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, makefile, gdb

My project is developed in C and call functions written in CPP. With the following option:
OPTS = -g
I can debug only my C programs. How to allow gdb debugger to step into the CPP programs.

Best,

Comment: `-g` should work for C++ too. We'll need more details (aka a [mcve]).

Comment: `OPTS` is not part of the implicit rules of gmake.  What is your compile rule for C?  What is your compile rule for C++?

Answer (score 1):

With GCC and Clang compilers both C flags and C++ flags are separate, I suspect your -g is only being passed to the c files and not the cpp files. Ensure you set both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` with -g. See here for a example https://stackoverflow.com/a/23407800/2729443

Comment: Thank you it works now by adding the same option for the C++.